# can't delete the head node of my linked list

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, codeblocks

I'm trying to create a sort of a simple compiler for a mini SQL language, and when I execute the algorithm there is a step when I need to call a function to delete the head node of a linked list(containing lexical units of the language)and assign the head to the second node. Inside the function, the code seems working just fine (when I print the list, the head is now the second node). but the change affection the original list is weird as the first head is still there but with a different value like 12321104(=p).so where is the problem
this is the structure of my linked list:

```
typedef struct U_Lexicale {
    char* Nom_UL; 
    int Type_UL; 
    int Ligne_UL;
    struct U_Lexicale* suivant;
} ElementUL;

void suppression(ElementUL* liste) {
    if (liste == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (liste != NULL) {
        ElementUL* tmp = liste;
        liste = liste->suivant;
        free(tmp);

        afficherListeUL(liste);
    }
}

suppression(copieAnalyseLex);
```

Comment: It's weird that you use `U_Lexicale` for the struct name and `ElementUL` for the typedef. Use the same name in both places to avoid confusion.

Comment: Style note: you don't need the second `if`. If `liste` is `NULL` the program will exit, and so the rest of the fucntion will not be reached. If that doesn't happen, then we already _know_ `liste` is not `NULL`.

Comment: And if you didn't exit, an `else` would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify `liste`, but you don't modify `copieAnalyseLex` to reflect that change.

```c
#include <assert.h>

void suppression(ElementUL** liste_p)
{
    assert( *liste_p != NULL );

    ElementUL* tmp = *liste_p;
    *liste_p = (*liste_p)->suivant;
    free(tmp);
}

suppression(&copieAnalyseLex);
afficherListeUL(copieAnalyseLex);
```